# How to match text, numbers, and white space characters for all languages in Javascript using XRegexp

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

Context:

I am improving a custom token parsing engine, and want to support characters, numbers and space characters in different languages.

Currently, This works with English characters and numbers with the following regex

```
var pattern = /\{\{someText\(?(\d+)?\|?([\w\d\s%]+)?\)?[\s\S]+\}\}/;

// this will extract the number and text in a token like
'{{someText(20|Hello World)}}'.match(pattern);

//output 
[20, 'Hello World']
```

But the above regex failed to parse characters in other languages:

```
'{{someText(20|abcdèfg)}}'.match(pattern);

//output 
[20, 'abcd']
```

Regex that I have tried:

I tried using XRegexp with the below regex, but looks like it's not working as I expected.

```
var pattern = XRegExp(/\{\{customText\(?(\d+)?\|?([[\p{L}\p{N}_]\p{Nd}[\p{Z}\h\v]%]+)?\)?[\s\S]+\}\}/);

'{{someText(20|abcdèfg)}}'.match(pattern);

//output 
[20, undefined]
```

For the new engine, I want to support characters in other languages as well. So that the text in

```
'{{someText(20|abcdèfg)}}'.match(pattern);
```

will produce an output

```
[20, abcdèfg]
```

The format of this token is always like {{someText(number|'The actual text')}}

Comment: Will someText always have a number followed by some text?

Comment: And will the brackets always be parantheses, or can they be `[`, `{` as well?

Comment: Also, will there be a minimum of two strings separated by a pipe `|`, or can there be just one?

Comment: The format of this token is always like `{{someText(number|'The actual text')}}`

Comment: Does my answer solve your question?

Comment: Your regex contradicts what you say about the format that "is always like". Please add the requirements to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please discard the regex and take "{{someText(number|'The actual text')}}" as input, and the expected output is [number, 'The actually']. The "number" and "The actual text" need to be extracted from the token.

Comment: Then I'd try `{{someText\((\d+)\|'([^']*)'\)}}`, see https://regex101.com/r/YCsxlv/1

Answer (score 1):

This will allow test, number and spaces in all language

```
XRegExp("^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s[\\p{L}\\d]+)?$");
```

For one or more spaces in between

```
XRegExp("^[\\p{L}\\d]+(?:\\s+[\\p{L}\\d]+)*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out:

```
\{\{someText\(?(\d+)?\|?([^\n\r|]+)?\)?\}\}
```

As seen here, at **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/48CsR4/2)**

## Explanation -

According to the **[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w)**,

> If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

So, `\w` would naturally match any English character, not the ones with an accent.

A good workaround is to use `[^\n\r|]` instead of `[\w\d\s%]`, so that it matches every character, EXCEPT newlines and the pipe `|` symbol (for obvious reasons).

Also, you included a `[\s\S]+` for some reason, which would basically match every space and non-space character (that is, every character in existence). I removed that so you could match multiple occurrences of the pattern, even on new lines :)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't really care of the string contents, just use

```
// non-newline
/\{\{someText\((\d+)\|(.*?)\)\}\}/
// or any character at all
/\{\{someText\((\d+)\|([^]*?)\)\}\}/
// or not brackets
/\{\{someText\((\d+)\|([^)}]*?)\)\}\}/
```